# Как в PUG правильно выглядит шаблон многостраничного сайта?

Tags: html, css, pug

Обычно при создании многостраничного сайта для каждой страницы создается отдельный html файл: portfolio.html, about.html итд с похожим шаблоном

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <header class="header"></header>
   <div class="main">
    Контент страницы
   </div>
  </body>
  <footer></footer>
</html>
```

Как правильно должен выглядеть шаблон для других страниц на PUG? Понятно, что должен быть специальный pug шаблон, но как его структурировать и куда подключать? Вроде ерунда, а все же .Сначала я думал, что просто в index.pug подключаются через include подряд все страницы, типа include header.pug ,include main.pug, include footer.pug, но потом понял, что такое подойдет для лэнденга, но никак не для многостраничного сайта, а в сети нормального объяснения так и не нашел

Comment: Какой еще "специальный шаблон"... вместо того чтобы придумывать всякую ересь, глянь в официальной документации: что такое Pug, для чего он предназначен, и каким функционалом обладает.

Comment: Подключение Pug сводится к использованию его API, поэтому для начала надо определиться с тем где это планируется делать: в готовой SSG/SSR-утилите, в сборщике/таскере, или просто в шеллскрипте вызываемом вручную. А по содержимому - Pug ничего не знает о "многостраничниках" и "спецшаблонах", его дело разметку создавать: что в напишешь, то он и сгенерит. Соотв., для создания многостраничника нужно всего лишь минимальное понимание HTML, чтобы связать страницы гиперссылками.